# Python equivalent/alternative for Java field annotations

Tags: java, python, selenium, annotations, python-decorators

I recently moved from Java test automation to Python test automation. In Java, I would use a field annotation named `@Important` to specify which elements in the Page Object Model are important (so I can query the important elements for each page and check whether they are displayed). This looks similar to this:

```
class MyPageObjectModel {
    @Important
    @FindBy(...)
    WebElement myElement1;

    @Important
    @FindBy(...)
    WebElement myElement2;

    @FindBy(...)
    WebElement optionalElement;
}
```

I wonder whether something similar is available for Python? I found out about decorators, but those seem to be only applicable to functions and not to fields.

Comment: There is no Python equivalent to mark certain class attributes as such.

Comment: @MrsNickalo Thanks for the answer. Too bad there is no equivalent, I find it a quite useful feature of Java that creates easy-to-read code. Is there perhaps an alternative you can think of to do these kinds of operations? For instance, I could create a wrapper class for `WebElement` and give it a boolean field named `important`, but that seems like quite a large design tradeoff to me. Any other options?

Comment: I was reading through some stuff about data classes in python. https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html   You could have a parent class that only has the important variables, the child class can have the other ones, and then use the dataclass fields option to get the fields of the parent class for your query and use the fields option on the child class when you want to query all the fields. Not the best workaround but the only thing I could think of that might make your life a little easier...